# Regular expression for numbers with maximum 4 decimal values

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a regular expression where a number can accept maximum up to 4 decimal values.

Valid values:

```
1.2222
0.50
.50
```

Invalid values:

```
56.56666666
12.
```

Currently the regular expression I am using is `^\d+\.?\d{0,4}$`, this is not working in case of `.50` but its working for `0.50`.

Can some one please help me out.

Comment: It is not clear: do you test each number as a separate string? Are you validating or extracting? Or a list of values?

Comment: @Fildor That would a match a dot only string.

Comment: @AndersonPimentel Ah, right ... I knew there is a catch.

Comment: Sorry I am little bit weak in Regex, this is for validating a textbox.

Comment: Would "123" be valid?

Comment: Would "123" be valid? Yes

Comment: Try [`^(?=.)\d*(?:\.\d{1,4})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/DQmhea/1/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think that's perfect! Please post it as an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - you could just change your original pattern to `^(?=.)\d*(?:\.\d{0,4})?$` if "123." is valid.

Comment: @Brett If you are sure, you may post the answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - ah, you devil - that would match just the period, wouldn't it. :)

Comment: @Brett I did not really check that, but you are right. Since the reqs are not clear to me, I never post in such cases.

Comment: Thanks WiktorStribiżew, its working.

Comment: Oh sure, done..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the number formats you specified, use

```
^(?=.)\d*(?:\.\d{1,4})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DQmhea/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.)` - there must be at least 1 char in the string (or `(?!$)` - no end of string right after the start of string - no empty string allowed)
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,4})?` - an optional sequence  of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d{1,4}` - 1 to 4 digits
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
\d*\.\d{1,4}\b
```